# Is there a trading functionality?

Tags: warframe

Is there any way to trade weapons, warframes, blueprints, or materials in warframe? There isn't a page for it in my steam inventory, but I figured that that might just be because it can also be played without downloading it through steam (by downloading through the original developer's site instead). Is there in fact a way to do it in-game, or am I forced to sell my gear that I don't want, even if a friend needs it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can trade mods, keys and platinum with other players in the clan dojos, if both of you are over mastery rank 2. You have a limit on how many trades you can do each day and each trade costs credits as a trading tax.

<s>Warframe does not currently feature a trading system. The developers have stated on multiple live streams that they are planning on doing a limited trading system later on which would not involve direct trading of warframes, mods or materials. I have not seen or heard anything solid on it as of yet.</s>

Comment: I'll try to find the actual quotes from developers if I remember and have the time

Comment: FYI trading is now possible, within the clan dojo - http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Trade_System